# Finding a marginal CDF

Tags: probability, statistics

I am stuck finding a marginal CDF of X given the random variables $X$ and $Y$ with the joint density:

$f_{XY}(x,y)=2e^{-(x+y)}$ for $0<x<y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_X(x)=\int_x^{\infty} 2e^{-x-y} dy=2e^{-x}e^{-x}=2e^{-2x}$ for $0<x<\infty$. Also $F_X(x)=\int_0^{x} 2e^{-2t} dt =-e^{-2t}|_0^{x}=1-e^{-2x}, 0<x<\infty$.

Comment: Can you explain the second part ?
$F_X(x)=1-e^{-2x}$

Comment: @i9-9980XE I have added some steps to my answer.

Comment: Both of those answers constitute into the marginal CDF of X ?

Comment: Yes, $f_X$ is the marginal density of $F$ and $F_X$ is the marginal distribution function of $X$.