# Finding the probability of a joint density

Tags: probability, statistics

Given the joint density of two random variables $X$ and $Y$,

$f_{XY}(x,y)=2e^{-(x+y)}$ for $0<x<y$

How do I compute $P(Y<1|X=1)$?

I know the conditional probability formula is:

$P(Y<1|X=1)=\frac{P(X=1,Y<1)}{P(X=1)}=\frac{\int\int2e^{-(x+y)}dydx}{\int\int2e^{-(x+y)}dydx}$

However, I'm unsure about the bounds of the integral

Comment: All these questions you asked are based on the *same* idea: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3236648/computing-probabilities, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3236899/how-do-i-calculate-the-conditional-expectation,https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3236759/finding-the-conditional-density,https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3236631/finding-a-marginal-cdf ...Why not ask for the related ideas in a single question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDF tells us that $X<Y$ a.s. so that $P(Y<1\mid X=1)=0$.

Comment: oh my, I just had a brain fart. Thank you!