# Finding a joint CDF F

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Given the joint density of two random variables $X$ and $Y$,

$f_{XY}(x,y)=2e^{-(x+y)}$ for $0<x<y$

How do I find the joint CDF ?

I know it'll be:

$F_{XY}(x,y)=\int\int_R f_{XY}(x,y)=\int\int_R2e^{-(x+y)}dxdy$ for $0<x<y$

I am unsure what my regions would be but I am guessing it is from x to infinity and y to infinity.

Comment: Be careful: $\int_{-\infty}^x f(x)\, dx$ confuses free variables and bound variables.  You might anslo want to include a calculation of $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ when $x \gt y$, though you might be able to spot this is equal to $F_{X,Y}(y,y)$

Comment: Sorry, woulld that mean my bounds are incorrect? I thought x<y is omitted as it's 0<x<y

Comment: $$
\mathbb P(X\leqslant x, Y\leqslant y) = \int_0^{x\wedge y}\int_0^y f_{X,Y}(s,t)\ \mathsf dt\ \mathsf ds
$$

Comment: @math1000 can you explain that please ?

Comment: The point is that $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is a function on the whole of $\mathbb R^2$.  It is clearly $0$ if either $x$ or $y$ are negative, but you also need to deal with the case $0 \le x \le y$ as you do, and the case $0 \le y \lt x$

Comment: This pdf seems to be in high demand: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3237176/finding-the-probability-of-a-joint-density.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we have $0<x<y<\infty$, if we take $x$ as dependent on $y$, we get - 
$$\iint_R f_{XY}dx dy= \int_0^\infty\int_0^yf_{XY}dxdy$$
If we would take $y$ as dependent on $x$, we get -
$$\iint_R f_{XY}dx dy= \int_0^\infty\int_x^\infty f_{XY}dydx$$

Comment: For the first case, I got 1, and for the second case, I got -1.

Comment: Sorry, both are 1